# Interactive molecular machinery visualisation software?

Tags: molecular-biology, software, visualization

If I want to manually feed mRNA through a ribosome to actually see what happens step by step which software can I use to do that?

I'd like to be able to see changes in geometry and orientation at an atomic level. Maybe this doesn't exist yet, I don't know!

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We try to clarify questions before answering to avoid ambiguity. Your request for software for molecular visualization assumes that the necessary data input exists. This would presumably be in the form of atomic coordinates for all successive states involved in peptide bond formation of the same ribosomal machinery. Do you realize why such data are not available? If your objective is to understand the molecular interactions at each step in protein synthesis, what is wrong with original papers and standard molecular visualization of their data?

Comment: Hello thanks for the welcome. Well it sounds like I'm being too greedy and what I'm looking for doesn't exist. The atomic structure of the ribosome has been available for over 2 decades now so in answer to your question, no, I don't understand why a few successive states have not yet been recorded. The question comes from a desire to interact with and visualise molecular machinery at an atomic level, I wish to visualise the sequence of mechanical steps that happen in for example translation because visualising something is understanding something.

Comment: As you may know, one has to trap all the ribosomes in a particular state to be able to get the coords by X-ray or EM. This generally means using particular modified reagents or inhibitors. Using these techniques, we certainly have snapshots of several stages of protein synthesis — however half a dozen snapshots do not make a movie. I am sure some of the molecular viewers that take PDB coordinates allow one to align and load different structures in sequence — I imagine that you are familiar with them. If you like I can look out what different stage structures and  associated stuff is available.

Comment: I was imagining that if such a program exists it would rely heavily on modelling and simulation and not necessarily move through a sequence of perfect images. We can find so many animations nowadays and while not perfect they do a good job of giving us the general idea however I wish to go a little deeper. I have 2 jobs and I'm a student so reading through multiple papers, viewing static PDB files and trying to imagine the changes in positions and bonds all in my head seems too difficult and inefficient. I will try to create my own solution! Thank you for your help!